# Ubuntu Partition deleted and got i386 file not found error

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7

My query might be looking similar to others which are already posted here and in other forums. But i didn't see exact problem what i am facing. 
Here we go,

My mistakes:

1. Tried to install windows 8.1 on dual boot system.
2. In a hurry, forgot to change the boot options. So directly installed from the DVD which installed the Win8.1 OS in C drive by default. (Original Win7 is located here)
3. Tried to format the other drives from Win8.1 OS after OS installation.
4. Again unfortunately Ubuntu grub/OS got deleted, which lead me to grub rescue promt with next reboot.
5. Tried the steps as mentioned in [this link](https://askubuntu.com/a/519015/386978). But again and again a mistake done. Not followed all the steps. When i successfully rebooted i didnt update the grub. So, after one more reboot, it went to again grub rescue mode.
6. This time, the above steps didn't work. It is saying i386-pc/normal.mod not found.

Can any one help me to do clean OS installation with entire Hard disk format. (i want to format my all partitions and install the OS)

Thanks and Regards
Partha

Comment: "and install the OS" I assume you only want Ubuntu? Insert Live DVD, choose "install", delete all partitions when asked and repartition to you liking. This will delete all data from all operating systems. Mind though: if you want windows too... that is not something you should ask on a site dedicated to Ubuntu ;) Also consider virtualbox: install Ubuntu, virtualbox in Ubuntu, windows in virtualbox. That is guaranteed to be less hassle.

Comment: Is system older BIOS based or newer UEFI based. Install for both Windows & Ubuntu is different for each type. And how you boot installer is how it installs. So boot in correct mode if UEFI as it can be either mode. Older BIOS systems only have BIOS. Generally better to install Windows first, but it will want unpartitioned space as it does not correctly see Linux partitions. Or if just BIOS you need a primary NTFS partition with boot flag. If UEFI it needs lots of partitions.

Comment: Partha: any feed-back on above questions?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to remove all the partitions to install Ubuntu, the following steps would assist you:
1) Insert the Ubuntu installation disc in the drive and boot it.
2) At the partitioning screen, choose **Something else**. [image: Partitioning screen]

3) At the below prompt, select every partition you see in the list and press the "-" (minus) button to remove the partitions.
 [image: choose wisely!]

Now choose the partitions wisely (I recommend following this for a better understanding at the partition table: [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation/343352#343352) before proceeding)

The link states all the important stuff you might want to go through for A SUCCESSFUL installation.
Good lucK!